# Sex - in domain name is this bad?

Tags: domains

In short I am working with a company that does trade shows...

one of their new domain names has the word 'sex' in but completely innocently.

EXAMPLE:  www. someproductsexpo .com (Being 'some' 'products' 'expo').

The content is completely inoffensive and I do not see there being any other things that would flag either the web or any emails sent from anyone@someproductsexpo.com as inappropriate.

I was just wondering if any has experiences of any domains like this or comments to add?

Thanks

Comment: With SEO in mind I would not use words like sex, viagra, or bad words in a domain. But I don't know a good link reference to show you that is not good to use it.

Comment: There's a funny list of some unintentionally bad domain names at the following URL: http://www.grupthink.com:8080/topic/22/Easily_mispronounced_domain_names_What_are_your_favorites

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having certain words in your domain is never a bad thing as far as SEO goes. There are no blanket penalties for "bad words" as that is counterproductive to the search engines' goals. They can tell, and are always getting better at, determining if content is violating their terms of service without resorting to assumptions or blanket penalties.

They're also good at picking keywords out of run on words in domains, although if your run on words can be taken more then one way using a hyphen might be a good way to clearly delimit them to the search engines. (e.g. expertsexhange.com and whorepresents.com).

Comment: The only problem you might have is that you might be blocked by some website-blockers. I remember there was an issue with the website http://www.scunthorpe-united.co.uk . I'll leave you to work out why.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, Expertsexchange.com  changed their name to Experts-Exchange.com

Though I am not sure about SEO, you might want to consider other 'practical' consequences as well.

Comment: They changed their name not because of the word "sex" but because it reads "expert sex change" - which is really unfortunate for them I guess.

Comment: @Farseeker: agreed !